# How to access datahug API via HTTP Authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, http-authentication

In [Datahug's documentation](https://api.datahug.com/), it states, 'Authentication is performed using HTTP Basic Authentication - A Datahug username and password will be required in order to access the API.'

As a result, I've tried the below (with my username and password defined)

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://api.datahug.com/Contact/'
l = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I've also tried the following:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "https://api.datahug.com/Contact/test@test.com"
l = requests.get(url,auth=(username,password))
```

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't need to create a `HTTPBasicAuth()`, you can just pass the tuple `auth=(username, password)`.

Comment: Is that the actual URL that you are using (it 404s for me)? According to the documentation you need to append the contact to the url, e.g. `https://api.datahug.com/Contact/test@test.com`. So the next obvious thing to check is that your credentials are correct, and whether the contact you are requesting exists. Otherwise I don't see that you are doing anything wrong. Maybe you should contact their [support](https://api.datahug.com/#support)

Comment: Thanks - I've tried your solutions and updated question. I've sent this stackoverflow question to them so I'm hoping they can answer.

Comment: Do you have a real contact for which you are authorised? `test@test.com` is merely an example, I assume that you are using a genuine contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tracked the issue down to the Datahug Edition your account was configured to. It was `CRM Only` which at the moment doesn't allow API access. I've changed the account Edition to `Full` which will also give you access to the web app and you will also be able to make api calls.

You should now get a valid response when you make API calls.